# Process.Kill does not seem to work with iexplore.exe

Tags: c#

I am using watin for browser automation, and many browser windows get left open, and at the end I am using this to attempt to close them all:

```
        Process[] ieProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");

            foreach (Process ie in ieProcesses)
            {
                ie.CloseMainWindow();
                ie.Close();
                ie.Dispose();
            }
```

For some reason close, closemainwindow, and dispose, all will not close my iexplore processes. If I step through this part with the debugger, ieProcesses will have all the processes in it, normally ~10, and it'll go through the foreach for each one but watching in the task manager, none of them close.

This may have to do with that they are started in hidden windows maybe? but I'm not sure the right way to close them then. Any idea?

Comment: Do they not close at all or do they close and then 'recover' themselves?

Comment: What version of IE are you trying to close?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `ie.Kill()` method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx

Comment: I was going to say this, but you beat me to it. I got busy testing his code because it looks like it would work, and I can say that IE 9 did close with his code.

Comment: I'm confused. The questioner mentions `Process.Kill()` in his question's title, but then forgets it's the answer to his question? Good thing you were here to remind him about it :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yea i was surprised that the .Kill wasn't there as well

Comment: Well... This is embarrassing. I thought .Kill was the very first one I tried, before resorting to trying the other three. Decided I better double check.... Opps. Thanks for the help =)